# getting "Null Pointer Exception" while export excel file with xlsx extension in displaytag

Tags: export-to-excel

i want to open Excel file with xlsx extension in my project(project is already existing one used display tag for exporting xls).i want to use same display tag jar to export xlsx too.I just followed the steps mentioned in "stackoverflow" for exporting excel file with xlsx extension in displaytag,getting below "Null pointer Exception while running the project  after followed the steps mentioned.

Note:am using eclipse IDE,Tomcat 7.0 and decorator class in my jsp file using display tag -1.2 jar already used for exporting xls.

error is below,

```
root cause
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
org.displaytag.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:43)
org.displaytag.export.ExportViewFactory.registerExportView(ExportViewFactory.java:95)
org.displaytag.export.ExportViewFactory.<init>(ExportViewFactory.java:67)
org.displaytag.export.ExportViewFactory.getInstance(ExportViewFactory.java:79)
org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doStartTag(TableTag.java:753)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.commonmodule.ISpaceScreen52_jsp._jspx_meth_display_005ftable_005f0(ISpaceScreen52_jsp.java:548)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.commonmodule.ISpaceScreen52_jsp._jspService(ISpaceScreen52_jsp.java:291) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:337)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:234)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:211)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag.doEndTag(RenderTag.java:220)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.layout.DefaultLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(DefaultLayout_jsp.java:362)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.layout.DefaultLayout_jsp._jspService(DefaultLayout_jsp.java:210)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:659)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:633)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
enter code here
```

Comment: Also update your error **stacktrace**. Please post **full stacktrace** so I can help you more. Are you getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/displaytag/util/RequestHelperFactory` or `Null Pointer Exception`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23537742/1459174)

[Code for ExportViewFactory.java](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/xref/org/displaytag/export/ExportViewFactory.html)

Here in the code of [ExportViewFactory.java](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/xref/org/displaytag/export/ExportViewFactory.html) it gets all defined classes from `displaytag.properties` , So for option `[mymedia]` what class you have specified in `displaytag.properties`, it is not able to find it or it is getting null there. It means you have not specified any class name there.

If you have specified and also you have edited `MediaTypeEnum`

It is not used unless you set

```
export.[mymedia]=true
```

If the case is you have specified the name of the class and if it is not having proper constructor than the error can come in [ExportViewFactory.java](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/xref/org/displaytag/export/ExportViewFactory.html) at

```
   try
    {
        exportClass.newInstance();
    }
```

But you are getting `nullpointerexception` in [ExportViewFactory.java](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/xref/org/displaytag/export/ExportViewFactory.html) at

```
     try
     {
         exportClass = ReflectHelper.classForName(viewClassName);
     }
```

It simply means that  `viewClassName` String is **null**.

Please check your `displaytag.properties` file and add proper class to it.

```
 export.[mymedia].class=com.displaytag.export.views.myExcel2007ExportView
```

Make sure you package and class name are correct and they exist.

Comment: Actually smartDecorator  class is a customized class which is added in displaytag  .i got the above error becoz i have added displaytag-1.2.jar  from maven(which is nt hvg SmartDecorator class),tatsy throwed previous error.

once i added the customized display tag jar file it is throwing "Null Pointer Exception" as i posted in stackoverflow forum.
pls find the attached "errorstacktrace" and "ispacescreen52.jsp" and provide me the solution.